Can an axiomatic system $\mathcal S$ be consistent with the claim of its own inconsistency?
Considering the statement: $\mathrm{Con}(\mathcal S + \neg\mathrm{Con}(\mathcal S))$, is it possible for it to be true? Doesn't the negation of the consistency of a part of the axioms by another axiom make the whole system inconsistent?

true as in provable in $\mathcal S$ or as in true from the outside?

@univalence from the outside.

Sure - let $\mathcal S$ be peano arithmetic (and assume its consistency). Then, from the incompleteness theorems, you know that $\mathcal S \not\vdash \mathrm{Con}(\mathcal S)$. Thus, $\mathcal S + \neg \mathrm{Con}(\mathcal S)$ is consistent.
However, the (external) natural numbers don't form a model of it, since peano arithmetic is consistent. Instead, all the models contain nonstandard natural numbers that the model thinks are proofs of the inconsistency of PA.

I thought that if $\mathrm{Con}(\mathcal P)$ for a generic axiomatic system $\mathcal P$, then any other system obtained by "eliminating" some axioms had to be consistent, too. Am I wrong?

That is correct.

@Elvis yes: $\mathrm{Con}(\mathcal S)$ is true, but $\mathcal S$ isn't "aware" of that due to incompleteness!

@univalence got it, thanks
